# How to integrate an error function multiplied by a Gaussian

Tags: calculus

I wish to compute an analytic solution to

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, e^{-x^2} \operatorname{erf}(ax +b)$

I gave integration by parts a go but essentially ended up with the same integral. Anyone know if this can be solved?

Comment: Have a look at [4.3.13](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf).

Comment: Try a series solution for "small" values of $b$